# Wocoomerce - set discount to an order

Tags: php, woocommerce

I'm creating an order programmatically using `wc_create_order()`, and I couldn't find a way to set discount to the order, something like

```
$order     = wc_create_order();
$sub_total = $_POST['totals']['totalBefore'];
$discount  = $_POST['totals']['discount'];

$order->set_discount( $discount ); //this function doesn't exit, need something to do that work
$order->set_total( $sub_total - $discount );
```

Any idea how I get this?

Comment: Are you looking for the `WC_Coupon` class? https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Coupon.html

Comment: Is there any way to set order discount without involving coupons?